# "На дружеской ноге" - синоним

Tags: семантика

*Сразу оговорюсь: это не дубликат вопроса «На короткой ноге» — почему так говорят?" (ссылку не даю специально, чтобы не делать связанным).*

Ситуация следующая.
Некто всячески демонстрирует дружескую близость с лицами известными. Ну вот прямо-таки на манер Хлестакова.

> Литераторов часто вижу. С Пушкиным на дружеской ноге. Бывало, часто
> говорю ему: «Ну что, брат Пушкин?» — «Да так, брат, — отвечает,
> бывало, — так как-то всё...» Большой оригинал.

("Ревизор")

Как назвать его поведение? "Панибратство" и "амикошонство" не предлагать, эти понятия требуют общения непосредственного, а тут всего лишь демонстрация третьим лицам.

(+)====
@Eagle

> Они это делают, чтоб придать себе важность.
> Назовите это поведение одним словом. Это всё, что от вас требуется по теме вопроса.

(++)====
@Nadezhda

> Непросто сказать одним словом.

Попробую пояснить. Ситуация была следующая. В одном интернет-разговоре я назвал одного ныне покойного известного поэта просто по имени. Без всякой задней мысли, он был школьным другом моего отца и сам так представлялся.
В ответ услышал обвинения в амикошонстве, что показалось мне глубоко неправильным не только по сути, но и по выбору термина.
Вот я и задумался...

Answer (score 1):

Фанфаронство, бахвальство, псевдология? Стремление погреться в лучах чужой славы? Попытка примазаться к чужой славе? Стремление казаться больше, чем он есть, за счет создания впечатления, что он причастен к жизни великих, знаком с ними? Создание иллюзии своей значительности путем демонстрации своих связей с известными личностями? Непросто сказать одним словом.

Comment: Вижу, что вы хотите ответить по сути, но не совсем поняли ситуацию. Я для вас набросал несколько строчек в тексте самого вопроса... Но в силу личных причин хочу теперь сделать паузу. Когда и если вернусь на ресурс - продолжим.

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь ситуация понятна, и вопрос действительно в другом. Я-то думала, нужно именно поведение Хлестакова охарактеризовать как можно точнее. Думаю, что на правах друга можно назвать кого-то по имени. Жаль, что Вы хотите уйти, Ваши комментарии очень полезны.

Comment: мне нужен отдых, как минимум тай-аут. Про "уйти" я пока ничего определенного не говорил

Answer (score 0):

«На дружеской ноге» не означает «всячески демонстрирует дружескую близость с лицами известными».

Такой смысл у текста в целом.

> «Литераторов часто вижу»

> Видеть — видеться с кем-л., лично встретить кого-л. [словарь
> Евгеньевой]

Видеть — непосредственное общение. И «на дружеской ноге» это тоже непосредственное общение.

> **Быть на дружеской ноге.** Значение: **Держаться в близких, личностно-доверительных отношениях.** Происхождение: "Быть на короткой ноге"
> скопировано с французского être sur un bon pied – буквально "быть на
> хорошей ноге". Иногда встречается поэтому и на дружеской ноге, это
> отсюда же. Например у Гоголя: Вы, может быть, думаете, что я только
> переписываю; нет, начальник отделения со мной на дружеской ноге. Этак
> ударит по плечу: "Приходи, братец, обедать!" [[moiposlovicy.ru](https://moiposlovicy.ru/frazeologizmy/17)]

Тут вообще не известно, так ли это на самом деле. Есть люди, которые рассказывают, что у них трёхэтажный дом, Пугачёва в гости приходит и т. п.

Они это делают, чтоб придать себе важность.

И тут похоже такая ситуация. Человек выдает желаемое за действительное. Но это видно из всего текста, а не из отдельных слов.

Если кто-то скажет, что ему президент детей крестил, то «детей крестить» не значит «демонстрировать дружескую близость». Это значит совершать обряд крещения.

Такой смысл у всего текста, потому что понятно, что это малоправдоподобно и человеку хочется показать себя важным.

*«Быть на дружеской ноге»* можно заменить, я думаю, *«в хороших дружеских отношениях»*.

«Панибратство» и «амикошонство» не подходят, потому что это другое:

> ПАНИБРА́ТСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. Разг. Бесцеремонно-фамильярный. [словарь
> Евгеньевой]
>
> АМИКОШО́НСТВО, -а, ср. Разг. Бесцеремонное, неуместно-фамильярное
> обращение под видом дружеского. [словарь Евгеньевой]

Comment: *И «на дружеской ноге» это тоже непосредственное общение.*  Вы боюсь, не поняли не только вопроса, но и Гоголя. Хлестакова характеризует не общение с Пушкиным, а хлестаковщина, невероятные рассказы об этой близости. Ну с Гоголем ладно, каждый имеет право на свое прочтение, но вопрос-то явно не предполагал проверку вашего понимания Гоголя. ***Как назвать поведение Хлестакова именно в этом отрывке?***

Comment: *«Панибратство» и «амикошонство» не подходят, потому что это другое:* - Другое, чем что? Чем "на дружеской ноге"? Другое, но не такое уж далекое. А если вы имели в виду мой вопрос, так ***назовите это "другое"***.  Вы очень много наговорили, но все не по вопросу.

Comment: *Они это делают, чтоб придать себе важность.*
***Назовите это одним словом.*** Это всё, что от вас требуется по вопросу.

Comment: @behemothus У вас вопрос «„На дружеской ноге“ — синоним». Синоним это слово такое же или очень похожее по смыслу. На самом деле вы хотите узнать, как одним словом назвать поведение Хлестакова. Это разные вещи.

Comment: @behemothus *«Под „хлестаковщиной“ понимают пустое хвастовство, основанное на лжи, не подкрепленное ничем реальным, стремление казаться тем, кем ты не являешься»* [[yandex.ru](https://yandex.ru/q/question/chto_takoe_khlestakovshchina_eto_iavlenie_1b8f0dcd/)]. Не знаю, что я неправильно понял.

Comment: @behemothus Такое поведение можно назвать: *бахва́льство, а, мн. нет, ср. (простореч.). Самонадеянное хвастовство, преувеличенное восхваление своих сил и способностей [словарь Ушакова]*. Может ещё: *похвальба́, ы́, р. мн. нет, ж. (разг.). Хвастливое выставление напоказ своих достоинств; кичливое хвастовство [словарь Ушакова]*. Но это не синонимы к «на дружеской ноге».

Comment: @behemothus *«Другое, чем что?»* «Быть на дружеской ноге» — это на самом деле хорошо дружить с кем-то (Хлестаков об этом врёт, но значение от этого не меняется), а «панибратство» и «амикошонство» — это вести себя так, как будто ты близкий друг, хотя ты не друг; и это неприятно получателю такого отношения. Это как прийдя к чиновнику на приём, обнять его, называть ласково по имени и т. п.

Comment: @behemothus Ещё есть слово «рукопожатый». [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9): *неол., неодобр. человек, считающийся своим в определённом сообществе, где ему готовы пожимать руку.* Можно в каком-то смысле сказать: *«Он называл себя рукопожатым в обществе литераторов»*.

Comment: @behemothus Ещё есть слово РИСОВА́ТЬСЯ чем и без доп. *Стараться показать себя с выгодной стороны, стремиться вызвать чем-л. интерес к себе* [словарь Евгеньевой].